# How to detect pitch on windows phone?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, fft

I know this is a rather general question, and apologies - I just can't find a start to this question anywhere.  I'm currently building an app at a hackathon that will take voice/piano melody and decipher its pitch.  I have found several javascript libraries that only work on servers, and do not work at all on WP.
I know a tuner can be done as I've seen several guitar tuner-type apps on the store, but I have no understanding of how to achieve the same result (and neither do the Microsoft representatives present) although I was suggested to look at FFT.

Again, I apologize for the general nature of this question.  I would provide more information if I had it.  Thanks.

Comment: Generally you'd use a Fast Fourier Transform -- FFT.

Comment: Well, the first thing I want to ask is, what is the form of input? Meaning, are you talking into the microphone? Or is it music/vocal/whatever on the system itself that you want to check the pitch of? Depending which it is will require 2 completely different answers

Comment: Just a simple tone - one piano note, or one person singing.  Nothing like music or orchestrated patterns.

Comment: Right right, but what is the form of input? Will you be using the microphone? Or is it just to analyze audio data that is already on the phone?

Comment: Ah, yes.  From the phone microphone - Live sound.

Comment: Ahhh, and sorry it took so long, you should really use the @ sign so people will get notifications that you responded. In that case, my other question is, how will you want that data outputted? Are you talking semitones? A letter referencing a key? Scopes?

Comment: @DreadHeadedDeveloper We will be referencing letter names - like C0, C#2, E1, etc.

Comment: Oh, well that's easy then! Hell, there are plenty of apps out there that can do it for you! Do you need to build code that can do that?

Comment: @DreadHeadedDeveloper I need to implement it in my own app.  I need to access the windows phone mic, get the audio, and figure out the key in javascript

Comment: Got it, alright, well it'll prolly take me a day or 2 to come up with everything, but in the meantime, I'll try to point you in the right direction. I recommend that you google "Developer console windows 8 phone" You can use it to develop apps, but also to access  parts of your phone like the mic

Comment: Another thing, do you actually have the phone? If you don't, developing for it will be difficult to test (depending)

Comment: Hey, back, I don't think I'll be able to help you out too much. Problem is, I did a little research and downloaded a few of the dev kits, none of them will let me program since my computer is outdated (Windows 7). As a result, I won't be able to do much for you, sorry mate! :(